# Estoy intentando validar un password y me aparece un:"Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 "

Tags: php, mysqli

//este es el código que estoy usando

```
<?php
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$clave=$_POST['password'];

//conectar a la base de datos
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$consulta="SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario='$usuario' and password='$clave'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($link,$consulta);
```

//en la declaración de la variable $filas me aparece el error
$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

```
if($filas>0) { 
    header("location:test.html");
}
else { 
    echo "Error en la autenticación";
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);  //y en el mysqli_free_result aparece otro error
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: En `mysqli_connect` te falta la base de datos a la cual te vas a conectar.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías revisar si la consulta devuelve datos, algo así:

```
if(!empty($filas) AND mysqli_num_rows($filas) > 0)
    header("location:test.html");
else
    echo "Error en la autenticación";
```

Saludos.